# facebook-style dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to employ the use of this dropdown menu: http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown.html

On my site, this appear fine and functions, however the opened window is placed at an incorrect height and much to far to the right (**on my site**). On **jsfiddle** it's just placed too high, but at least the horizontal is correct.

The code:  http://jsfiddle.net/EA6LS/1/

I literally copy and pasted from the site's demo to make this, and I can't see anything that I may have left out... ideas appreciated.

**update**

Ok I just thought of something.  On my site, I define a page width of 900px.  If I use "inspect" on firefox, I can see that the JS is assigning a 215px (give or take) left margin to the dropdown.  That is probably accurate on my screen.  However, it's moving the element to the left of my defined 900px area, not on my screen.... So is this possible a `relative` vs. `absolute` issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the JavaScript code that positions the dropdown and just define it in the CSS.  If you position `.dropdown` relatively, `.dropdown_content` will be positioned relative to it's parent, which makes positioning easy:

```
.dropdown {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown .dropdown_content {
    ...
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Remove these lines of JavaScript:

```
var o = $(this).parent().find('.dropdown_button').offset();
var h = $(this).parent().find('.dropdown_button').height();
$(this).parent().find('.dropdown_content').css({'top':(o.top+h-1),'left':o.left});
```

(That is where your inline `top` and `left` values are coming from.)

Also, remove `overflow: hidden` from your `body` style definition.

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/EA6LS/2/

I also usually think it's a good idea to uncheck "Normalized CSS" in jsfiddle.  When debugging CSS, that can lead to confusing results.

While you're at it... that JavaScript can be simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/EA6LS/4/

Comment: What if I want to always force each line in an <li> to stay on one line?

Comment: @Shackrock - Set `white-space: nowrap;` in the `li` style definition: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/EA6LS/5/

Answer (score 0):

The content inside the drop down has a margin-top of 11px, though I can't spot where it is defined at the moment.

Defining it right in the css seems to resolve your issue of the height being offset.

```
.dropdown.open .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 11px;    
}
```

EDIT: It seems that in chrome the user agent's stylesheet for ul, menu, and dir has

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
```

which is the culprit (for me at least)

EDIT2: They've inlined the css (via jQuery in the wrong manner), which is also why you're getting offset error

```
<ul class="dropdown_content" style="top: 135px; left: 164px; ">
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickbabcock/EA6LS/3/) for the "correct" looking drop down.  As per in the comment, here are the changes (note that in the javascript I deleted the part where it was setting the top of the drop down content):

*CSS*

```
.dropdown.open .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;    
}
```

*javascript*

```
$(this).parent().find('.dropdown_content').css({'left':o.left});
```

Comment: Odd.  Any idea why on my site (which, granted, does have a bit more going on) the "left:" inline property that is given to the dropdown is a few hundred px away?

Comment: Aha, so the inline CSS moves an "additional" XXpx beyond what my already defined boundaries are...   hmmmm, what would be a fix to that.  Something in jQuery I imagine?

Comment: To fix it, I would remove the inlined styles.  Set margin-top: 0 for .dropdown_content.  Then, via jQuery, set the left property of the dropdown_content to that of the actual dropdown